# Databases - How to handle optional columns?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

i have a simple database with 3 tables.

In the `users` table i simply store the information and his role. In the `locations` table i simply store more user information.

Now here is the thing, the column `pickup_instrucntions` is a optional column, meaning only a user with a specific `role` can store. So an example would be a user with `role_id = 1` can't store in `pickup_instrucntions` but user with `role_id = 2` can, leaving one row `NULL` and the other with inserted data.

Here is my schema:
[image]

Now it does get the job done but is this is good practice? Is there a better way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, most application I've seen just allow the optional column to have NULL, and leave it to the application code to "do the right thing."

You *could* design a schema that prevents improper use of that attribute, but that gets into Fifth Normal Form territory. You can do it, but it takes time and focus to design a schema like that. It's more work than most people want to put into a single attribute in one table.

Comment: Nullable columns & rearrangements for subtypes doing or undoing outer joins have nothing to do with normalization to higher NFs & its reconstructions via natural joins per se. Some SQL idioms for constraining subtypes involve a column with only one (type tag) value, which violates 2NF, but it doesn't matter since such a table is essentially a view & the denormalization problems are traded off.

Comment: @philipxy It sounds like you want to post an answer.